# Problema para ajustar y alinear columnas, grid system

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un pequeño problema para ajustar columnas, según [bootstrap y su grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) se usa col, col-md, col-ml, col-sm, col-lg y sus demás variantes.

Resulta que en cuanto al diseño de la siguiente imagen

[image: Imagen columnas]

Según tengo entendido el grid system tiene hasta 12 columnas.
Mi idea es que la caja grande de arriba sea más chica (apliqué col-md-8) y para los contactos (id1 e id2) apliqué col-md-4 pero lo extraño es que la caja grande de arriba se mueve a la izquierda y los contactos no suben.

Ajunto código a continuación:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<title>Chat con nodejs + socket.io</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
    h2 {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .input-group-addon{
      background-color: rgb(2, 117, 216);
      color: #efefef;
    }
    #messages {
      padding: none;
    }
    .chat-window {
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 1rem;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .msg {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
.id{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#feedback p{
    color: #aaa;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
#output strong{
    color: #575ed8;
}
#chat-window1{
    height: 0px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2>Websocket & Socket.io Chat</h2>
</div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="chat-window">
              <div id="message">
        </div>

      <div id="chat-window1">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="feedback"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="controls">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-group" id="channel" name="channel" role="tablist">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="id1" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home">id1</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="id2" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home">id2</a>
        </div>
      </div></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="input-group enter-chat-message">
          <input id="handle" type="hidden" value="usuario1" placeholder="Handle" />
                    <input type="text" id="messages" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Chat Message...">
          <button id="btn" class="input-group-addon submit-chat-message" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">Send</button>
</div></div></div></div>


    </div></div></div>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El objetivo es que quede algo como la imagen a continuación:
[image: Objetivo]

Gracias de antemano, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que este es el resultado que quieres obtener, dale a ver en página completa.

```css
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css");
 h2 {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .input-group-addon{
      background-color: rgb(2, 117, 216);
      color: #efefef;
    }
    #messages {
      padding: none;
    }
    .chat-window {
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 1rem;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .msg {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
.id{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#feedback p{
    color: #aaa;
    padding: 1px 0px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
#output strong{
    color: #575ed8;
}
#chat-window1{
    height: 0px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2>Websocket & Socket.io Chat</h2>
  </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-group" id="channel" name="channel" role="tablist">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="id1" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home">id1</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" name="cod" value="id2" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home">id2</a>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="chat-window">
              <div id="message">
        </div>

      <div id="chat-window1">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="feedback"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
<div class="input-group enter-chat-message">
          <input id="handle" type="hidden" value="usuario1" placeholder="Handle" />
                    <input type="text" id="messages" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Chat Message...">
          <button id="btn" class="input-group-addon submit-chat-message" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">Send</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Tienes un problema con el anidamiento de columnas, observa tu código y fíjate que tienes una columna sin `row`. Cualquier cosa puedes comentar.

Comment: muy agradecido! funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias por su tiempo y disposición!